# Bash script to find and execute more complex command

Tags: bash, find, exec

Ok, so I have a bunch of `test_xx` and `validate_xx` files that I want to execute in the following way:

```
./path/test_01 | ./server | ./path/validate_01

./path/test_02 | ./server | ./path/validate_02
```

... And so on.

Now then, I want to create a `run_all` script that will locate all of these other scripts and run them all in this way.

I can use the following code to find and execute only, for example, test_01:

```
find ./*/ -name test_01 -exec {} \;
```

So, I have two problems:

1. (Important!) How can I make bash execute the more complicated line above, with piping and two unknown directories to search for? I can only find how to execute a single command.
2. (Less important, but still an issue...) What would be the best way to loop this script, so that it executes all test/validate scripts in the directory, then stops? The scripts are currently named test_01, test_02, ..., test_26 (and similarly for validate_xx) - but I want to script to still work, without changing, if I add test_27 etc.

Comment: Try this one: find . -name "test_*" | xargs -i sh -c '{} | ./server | `echo {} | sed 's/test_/validate_/'` '

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they don't span multiple directories, you don't need to use `find`:

```
for test in path/test*; do $test | ./server | ${test/test/validate}; done
```

BTW, useful tidbit: `${a/b/c}` syntax says: take value of variable `a`, and replace `b` with `c`.

If you do need find, then you can wrap redirection inside a shell script:

```
find dir -exec sh -c '... | ... | ...' \;
```

EDIT: in a bit more detail,

```
find . -name test\* -exec sh -c '
  test={}
  validate=${test/test/validate}
  $test | ./server | $validate
' \;
```

Comment: Tests are stored in different folders, so I do need to use find -- sorry, I should have been clearer there. (However, each test_xx script is in the same folder as its corresponding validation_xx script -- so it's probably possible to use some shortcut here)


The relevant bit of code now looks like this: (starting with i="1")


     find ./*/ -name test_0$i -exec sh -c '{} | ./server'

...Which works, so it seems I'm on the right track. But how to incorporate validate_01? Hmm...

Comment: @TomLord: Okay, I believe this should do the trick. No need for an explicit loop, `find` itself is all the loop you need.

Comment: Thank you!! The "EDIT" you added above works perfectly, and without the need for any indexing variables like I was attempting.
I'll come back and upvote your response once I've been on this site long enough for it to allow me to, haha!

Comment: Your use of `find` is broken here if any files contain whitespace or embedded semicolons.  Also, the invocation is broken if the script exists in a directory with spaces.  It should be: `find . -name 'test*' -exec sh -c '"$1" | ./server | "${1/test/validate}"' _ {} ';'`

Comment: @JoshCartwright: In general case, yes. I was trusting the OP that his files were `test_##` and `validate_##`, which do not necessitate quotage. I guess that part of the answer was tailor-made for the question.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `for` loop. For example, you can loop over the tests and extract the number from them via Parameter expansion:

```
for test in ./path/test_[0-9][0-9] ; do
    "$test" | ./server | ./path/validate_${test: -2}
done
```